# Is it possible to halt execution of a Jupyter notebook using papermill?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipython, papermill

I have a set-up whereby I have a few Jupyter notebooks that are parameterised so I can run them from another notebook.

I'm using the `papermill` module to do this which is quite convenient. The simplest way of running looks something like this

```
path = '/path/to/notebook.ipynb'
pm.execute_notebook(
   path,
   path,    
)
```

What I would now like is to have the ability of halting execution **from within the notebook being run** if certain conditions are not met.

Is there a way of doing this with papermill and, if not, is there another module that can do this?

Comment: Have you tried using sys.exit(0)?

Answer (score 4):

You can raise either SystemExit(0) or SystemExit('') directly or via sys.exit(0). Papermill is designed to ignore these errors: https://github.com/nteract/papermill/pull/449

Comment: Thanks, I confirm that `sys.exit(0)` halts the execution of a notebook, by working as a silent "break" or as an "early return".

Answer (score 1):

I would just use `assert not failure_condition, "My condition failed"` inside the notebook to force an exception to be raised. This will halt execution and raise an exception that papermill will wrap in a `PapermillExecutionError` in the parent process which called `pm.execute_notebook`.