# Using papermill CLI how to finish earlier a jupyter notebook if certain conditions are not met?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipython, papermill

Papermill throws exception if I need to finish the code earlier. For example with quit():

```
nbclient.exceptions.DeadKernelError: Kernel died
```

I would like to know if there is a way to instruct the code exit without papermill throwing the exception.

Example:

```
# check conditions if all met then run full notebook
# if not, then just finish

condition1=True

if condition1:
    quit() # if condition is not met then finish here

print('continue the logic')
```

Comment: Are you running papermill inside the Notebook using Python ? Why don't you catch the exception with try/except?

Comment: I am running the notebook with papermill in a shell; the difference here is the notebook might need to finish earlier the execution, not going to complete the entire notebook; when that happens papermill throws exception described in the question. Want the notebook execution to stop if condition not met and papermill to do not throw exception.

Comment: You can try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55478353/bash-script-with-multiple-papermill-commands-does-not-fail-on-notebook-errors. Basically papermill will return a non-zero exit code which you can catch with shell $?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `sys.exit()`, or equivalently `raise SystemExit`, as indicated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73767927/1265409). This works because the argument to `sys.exit()` has a default value of 0, meaning "successful termination". See the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html):

> The optional argument arg can be an integer giving the exit status (defaulting to zero), or another type of object. If it is an integer, zero is considered “successful termination” and any nonzero value is considered “abnormal termination” by shells and the like.

Note: it used to be that using `sys.exit()` would stop `papermill`, but an [issue](https://github.com/nteract/papermill/issues/435) was raised and [fixed](https://github.com/nteract/papermill/pull/449).